# Array of var array

Tags: c#, arrays, var

I do not know if this is even possible, but I am using a LINQ query and storing my object results in an implict variable or var like this:

```
var List= from Person in GlobalVariables.Person List where Person.TeamID == CurrTeam select Person;
```

What I am asking for is there any way to make an array of vars? (Meaning each row will have another array of objects stored in it)

When I try it it does not recognize var as a valid type. Any way on how to do this or an alternative?

Comment: You're misunderstanding `var`.  Please show us what you're trying to write?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`var` is not a type. It is a way to not say what the type it. This is known as implicit typing - the compiler can infer what the *actual* type is.

C# is still a strongly typed language.

```
var myVar = "a string"; // type of myVar is System.String
```

You can have an array of array ([jagged array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s05feca.aspx)) in C#, if that's what you need.

Comment: Ok. Then i need to find out what is the type of the result of this statement 
"from Person in GlobalVariables.Person List where Person.TeamID == CurrTeam select Person"

So that i can use it as type for my array

Answer (score 0):

In this case here var is *really* some collection-type with generic type `Person` and you can of course declare an array of `Person`-Objects in this case (just wrapp the linq-expression in (..) and add `.ToArray()` for example.

Maybe what you want is either a array of `object` that can hold any type or a array of some base-type of `Person` or even a `dynamic[]`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you're after in this case, but here's one guess:

```
var List= (from Person in GlobalVariables.PersonList 
           where Person.TeamID == CurrTeam 
           select Person).ToArray();
```

The List will now be a `Person[]` (assuming Person is of type Person.)